# html Drag&Drop for text

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

i am developing an online registration tool for sportevents where user can register them for some events. The admin of an event can edit the email that gets send to the users when he registers.

Now i wan´t to add some variables to this email in the form [teamname].
I wan´t to show the admin all the possible variables in a list with divs or something else so he could drag one of them into the textarea and on the dragging position the right text gets displayed. kinda like the code-tags here but with drag&drop functionality.
I already looked at some jQuery solutions, but it looks to complicated for such a easy problem.

Did anyone have an idea how i can make this possible?

EDIT:
i only wan´t to ad some text to a textarea! The text in this textarea gets then send over to the user via mail. So the javascript should only copy a specific text to the drop position in the textarea. The text should deppend on which element drag from an list of  container or some other html tag.

EDIT2:
I found this: http://skfox.com/jqExamples/insertAtCaret.html
Thats very close, but i wan´t to insert the text on the position where i drop the element

Thanks, Yannick

Comment: This is far more complicated than you think, considering how HTML is poorly-supported in emails. I suggest using an existing service that gives you email templates with data merge functionality, such as: http://www.campaigner.com/

Comment: you can't run JS in HTML emails, or at least, no email app i've seen allows that...

Comment: oh i thing you got me wrong i will edit my question